# How do you convert file data to a string and vice versia?

Tags: c#, file, base64, tobase64string

Let's say i have a .xlsx file, with password protection, i want to convert this to a string format, and then later when be able to reconstruct the string back to the original .xlsx file keeping all properties (such as the password protection...)

I Tried changing the extension from .xlsx to a .txt, transferring the string content of the .txt and then changing the .txt back to .xlsx... but the file would be corrupted... any ideas?

I Hope my question is clear enough!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Encode the file to base64 format. Than Decode it to whatever it was before.

Comment: I agree that base64 is the way to go, but it's important to note that this isn't encryption - it's not like this actually "hides" the data at all.

Comment: I'm not looking for encrypting or protecting any of the data actually, just a way to transfer a string version of a file format (ex .xlsx) then reconstructing it with all the content/properties intact.

Comment: @AliAlnuaimi this is not for security reason. This is just for converting everything to string and than recover the file from that.

Comment: @AliAlnuaimi: I understand that. I just want to make it clear to anyone reading the answer that base64 encoding it *not* a form of encryption.

Comment: @JonSkeet I replaced encrypt with encode. thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to convert this to a string format

Firstly, I'd encourage you *not* to do this unless you really need to. The more conversions you do, the more room there is for error.

However, it's not terribly difficult to do if you *really* need to - what you're looking for is *base64 encoding* which can take arbitrary binary data and encoding it into ASCII text - then you can decode the text back to the binary data.

Here's sample C# code to do it:

```cs
public static void Base64EncodeFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFile);
    string text = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    File.WriteAllText(outputFile, text);
}

public static void Base64DecodeFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(inputFile);
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
    File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, data);
}
```